# tensorflow serving - batching reshape error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, batching

I'm using [inception_client.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py) to perform predictions with tensorflow serving and it works very well. But when I'm trying to batch the images on request and execute, tensorflow serving API raises this exception:

> AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="Input to reshape is a tensor with 20480 values, but the requested shape has 2048
>        [[Node: pool_3/_reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _output_shapes=[[1,2048]], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](pool_3, pool_3/_reshape/shape)]]")

As a pre-process, I've readed two images, converted to tensor, normalize and create a list to use on `make_tensor_proto`:

```
proto = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(images, shape=tf.shape(images).numpy().tolist())
request.inputs['image'].CopyFrom(proto)
result = stub.Predict(request, 120.0)
```

I've created this model using [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py), retraining InceptionV3 model

Anybody can help to understand this problem?